# Disabling/changing keywords in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I frequently use the "quick open" functionality in VS code, and it works quite well. However, there is one somewhat frustrating issue - there are keywords that prevent me from finding what I'm trying to open.

Specifically, we have a "task" entity in our code that has dozens of files, and I often need to go to "task.module.ts" or "task.service.ts" (or many others with similar names starting with "task"), but "task" is a reserved word in the quick open menu, and it says "No tasks matching" when I type "task module", for example.

Is there any way to disable this? Or is there another shortcut that would let me go to files that *doesn't* have this keyword functionality? I don't particularly need or want to run tasks from the quick open, I just want to go to the task file I'm trying to find.

Comment: Don't type the space after `task`?

Comment: Ah, that's a good thought. It just uses the spaces for hints anyway, I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the spaces are just hints anyway, Quick Open is perfectly capable of finding the given files even without putting a space. So instead of typing "task module", just typing "taskmodule" works.

It'll probably take a little getting used to not instinctively hitting space, but otherwise this is a perfectly fine solution.